# using dnnConfirm after NodeEdited in RadTreeView

Tags: javascript, telerik, dotnetnuke, confirm, radtreeview

I have a RadTreeView like this:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView runat="server" ID="rtvNodes" DataFieldID="ID" DataFieldParentID="CategoryID" DataValueField="ID"
                    AllowNodeEditing="true"
                    OnClientNodeClicking="ClientNodeClicking"
                    OnClientNodeEdited="OnClientNodeEditedHandler">
  <DataBindings>    
    <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding
        Depth="1"
        Checkable="false"
        TextField="Name"
        ValueField="ID"
        Expanded="false"
        CssClass="rootNode confirm" />
    <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding
        Depth="0"
        Checkable="false"
        TextField="Name"
        ValueField="ID"
        Expanded="true"
        CssClass="rootNode confirm" />
  </DataBindings>      
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

I want to show confirm dialog box by **dnnConfirm** after edit node text in tree. I used this code for this issue:

```
function OnClientNodeEditedHandler(sender, eventArgs) {
        $("<a href='#' />").dnnConfirm({
            text: 'Are you sure?',
            yesText: 'Yes',
            noText: 'No',
            callbackTrue: function () {
                // set a hidden filed                
            }
        }).click();
    }
```

After edit node text `dnnConfirm` appears but before confirming closes.

It would be very helpful if someone could explain solution for this issue.